# can't solve this definite integral: $4\pi \int_1^e \frac{\ln x}{ x} \; d x$

Tags: definite-integrals

please help me with this integral, I can't figure out how to solve it from the manual.

$$ 4\pi\int_1^e \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x 
$$

Comment: When you say (lnx)' do you mean $\frac{1}{x}$ or is that just a typo, and the integrand is $ln^2(x)$?

Comment: that's not a typo, it's 1/x

Comment: Then it's trivial, let $u = ln(x)$ and $du = \frac{dx}{x}$.

Comment: You should learn to use math markup also in titles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$4\pi \cdot \int_{1}^e lnx \cdot (lnx)' dx = 4\pi \int_{1}^e \dfrac{lnx}{x} dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 4\pi \cdot ((lnx)^2)|_{x = 1}^{e} = 2\pi$

Comment: i don't get it, how do you integrate lnx/x ?? where did the 1/2 came from

Comment: He used a u-substitution to get the integral to be of the form $\int u du = \frac{1}{2} u^2$ by the power-rule for integration.

Answer (score 2):

$$4\pi\int_1^e(\ln x)(\ln'x)\,dx=4\pi\int_1^e \frac12(\ln^2 x)'\,dx=2\pi(\ln^2 e-\ln^2 1)=2\pi$$